# How to store data from fetch("URL").then() to a variable in java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to load a data from a url to a variable using .ready() but the alert box provides a undefined value, please help.

```
    let getMasterProd = () => {
        return fetch('url').then(data => data.json());
    }



    $( document ).ready(function() {
        var data =getMasterProd();
        alert(data);
    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for 'undefined' is probably because of the async nature of the fetch call. If you really want to provide the alert try using it inside then():

```
fetch('url').then(function(data){alert(data)});
```

You can also use async ajax call to fetch data but this is not recommended. If you can provide actual scenario then it will be more convenient for me to answer. Or you can try something suggested previously:

```
 let test;
console.log(fetch('url').then(function (data) {
  test = data;
}));
setTimeout(function () {
  alert(test);
}, 500);
```

For detail refer: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should also work:

```
  function $_GET(q, s) {
    s = (s) ? s : window.location.search;
    var re = new RegExp('&amp;' + q + '=([^&amp;]*)', 'i');
    return (s = s.replace(/^\?/, '&amp;').match(re)) ? s = s[1] : s = '';
  }
```

Just call it like this:

```
var value = $_GET('myvariable');
```

Comment: This won't work properly if the return took more than 500ms. It's not a good solution to use setTimeout for async calls IMHO.

Comment: i put some changes. check that out

Comment: This is not what he wants. He wants "to load a data from a url" not to get the value of a url parameter

Answer (score 0):

`fetch` returns a `Promise` not data.

```
const getMasterProd = () => fetch('url').then(data => data.json());

$(document).ready(() => {
    getMasterProd()
    .then((data) => {
      alert(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Give this a try,

```
fetch('url').then(data => { return data.json() });
```

Also, you should consider using axios.

Comment: You will get a `SyntaxError` with this code. You must add curly brackets with `return`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. It's by mistake. Corrected the same.